# Hi i want to change from hamburgur to cross on click of the menu

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, css

Hi I am working on a Shopify website. i want the hamburger menu to change to cross on click, I have tried everything but it is not working. i have two different images one hamburger and another is cross. and I have given them two different classes as well

Site URL:"https://9q49gu54zvkaspm1-18691129395.shopifypreview.com/"

Please help

```js
if($('body').hasClass(".show-mobile-nav"))
{
  $('img.close').hide();
} 
else($('body').hasClass(""))
{
  $("img.open").show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

here is the code I have tried

Comment: You should add your html also to the snippet

Comment: <div>
    <a class="toggle-mob-nav" href="#" aria-controls="mobile-nav" aria-label="{{ 'layout.header.open_mobile_nav_aria_label' | t | escape }}">
      
     <img class="open" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0186/9112/9395/files/menu_1.png?v=1611225150"> 
    <img  class="close" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0186/9112/9395/files/cancel_66167bb4-4b7c-4b5a-8ed8-2d972178387d.png?v=1611225150"> 
    
    
    
    </a><br>
    <span>MENU</span>
  </div>

Comment: Not here 
click the edit button ->  below the snippet is a button to edit the snippet -> insert your html in the html quarter

Answer (score 1):

You could try doing something like this. Just have a span, and you make the two other bars with `::before` and `::after`

[Here is a codepen](https://codepen.io/bobsfriend/pen/VwKgEGV?editors=1000)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
}

ul,
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
  color: white;
  background: #393e46;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
}
nav h3 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0.5em;
}

.mobile-nav {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #393e46;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: right;
  transform: scale(1, 0);
  transform-origin: top;
  transition: transform 400ms ease-in-out;
}
.mobile-nav a {
  color: white;
  padding: 0.25em;
  font-size: larger;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 150ms ease-in;
}

.mobile-nav-toggle {
  position: absolute !important;
  top: -99999px !important;
  right: -999999px !important;
}

.mobile-nav-toggle-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: 1.25rem;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 99999;
}

.mobile-nav-toggle:focus ~ .mobile-nav-toggle-label {
  outline: 3px solid rgba(0, 172, 181, 0.75);
}

.mobile-nav-toggle-label span,
.mobile-nav-toggle-label span::before,
.mobile-nav-toggle-label span::after {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: white;
  height: 2px;
  width: 2em;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 400ms ease-in-out;
}

.mobile-nav-toggle-label span::before,
.mobile-nav-toggle-label span::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
}

.mobile-nav-toggle-label span::before {
  bottom: 7px;
  transition: opacity 250ms ease-in-out 400ms;
}

.mobile-nav-toggle-label span::after {
  top: 7px;
}

.mobile-nav-toggle:checked ~ .mobile-nav {
  transform: scale(1, 1);
}

.mobile-nav-toggle:checked ~ .mobile-nav a {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 150ms ease-in 350ms;
}

.mobile-nav-toggle:checked ~ .mobile-nav-toggle-label span:before {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 250ms ease-in-out;
}

.mobile-nav-toggle:checked ~ .mobile-nav-toggle-label span {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.mobile-nav-toggle:checked ~ .mobile-nav-toggle-label span:after {
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(7px);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <h3 class="logo">Logo Here</h3>
  <input type='checkbox' id='mobile-nav-toggle' class='mobile-nav-toggle'>
  <label for='mobile-nav-toggle' class='mobile-nav-toggle-label'><span></span></label>
  
  
  <div class="mobile-nav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="mobile-nav-link">Home</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="mobile-nav-link">Features</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="mobile-nav-link">Pricing</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="mobile-nav-link">Resourses</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="mobile-nav-link">Contact</a>
</div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
if($('body').hasClass(".show-mobile-nav"))
{
  $('img.close').show();
  $("img.open").hide(); // remember to hide or show the other element as-well
} 
else($('body').hasClass(""))
{
  $('img.close').hide();
  $("img.open").show(); 
}
```

Of course it should be a in function where it is called when the page is loaded and when the user clicks on the said button.